# Ajax.beginform callback properties , can not understand the differences

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, ajax.beginform

I read an online document that describes the Ajax.Beginform callback properties  , as follow:-

- OnBegin (in jquert it is  beforeSend):- Called immediately prior to the request being sent
- OnComplete (in jQuery it is complete):- Called if the request is successful
- OnFailure (in jQuery it is error):- Called if the request fails
- OnSuccess (in jquery it is success):- Called when the request has completed, irrespective of whether the request succeeded or failed

now i can not understand what is meant by "***Called when the request has completed, irrespective of whether the request succeeded or failed***". let take the following examples:-

- now if i am returning http 401 error from my application , which one script will be called , i assume the OnFailure ?, or since i am returning a result the onsuccess will be called instead?
- and if an UN-handeled exception is raised , then i assume that the OnFailure will be called, but will the OnComplete fire also ?

Thanks
Thanks

Comment: Think of it as `finally`. The best way of testing this is to implement all callbacks.

Comment: i do not like testing something unless i have minimal understanding of the differences...

Comment: Life could get pretty boring that way...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There will always be a succession of 3 callbacks, assuming the server sends a response back (404, 500, 200, 302, etc.). The `OnBegin` callback is the first to get called. The request then gets sent and the server sends back an acknowledgement. If the request was successful, `OnSuccess` gets called; if not, `OnFailure` gets called. After either one of `OnSuccess` or `OnFailure` finishes executing, the `OnComplete` callback will be called.

You can "visualize" it this way:

```
          |--success -> OnSuccess() -->|
OnBegin-->                              >--> OnComplete
          |--error   -> OnFailure() -->|

------------time line-------------------------->
```

Of course, the success/error status needs to get back to the client first.

Comment: but sending 404 http error will be considered as OnSuccess of OnFailure ?,, since the server return a response ? or OnSuccess will fire only when returning http 200 ? can yuo adivce ?

Comment: 404 will be considered a _failure_. These callbacks assume that the server was reached and that it sent a response back to the browser. I think that everything in the 2xx and 3xx codes will be considered success and 4xx and 5xx failure. Depending on the circumstances. Of course, sending a redirect (301 or 302) to an AJAX request doesn't always make sense.

Answer (score 1):

It means that the given function will be called when the request is finished. Your request might be successful or failed for some reason, but the given function will be executed, regardless of whether the request was successful or failed.

Example:
You define a function, let's call it callback.

Case1: You send a request, it reaches the server successfully and after the response, callback is executed.

Case2: You send a request, which is not successful, for instance the target does not exist. callback will be executed in this case as well.

[image]

Comment: as i understand these options that success is one of the available CAllBACKS and not a decision point ?? can you explain your picture please?

Comment: Off course. You have a callback for success as well, which executes after the request if and only if it was successful. On the other hand, this "Called when the request has completed, irrespective of whether the request succeeded or failed" refers to complete, I believe. Success callback is executed if and only if the request was successful, fail callback is executed if and only if the request has failed. The quote referred to the completed callback. The request will be completed regardless of whether the request was successful. My flowchart illustrates the complete callback logic.

Comment: so what is meant by if the request is successful ? is sending http 404 considered a success response , because the server respond back ? or Onsuccess will only fires in case the server return http 200 ?

Comment: Possible causes of failure are timeout, error, abort and parseError. complete callback is executed even if the request failed, timed out, errored out, aborted or had error in parsing. Success callback is executed if and only if the request was sent successfully and the response arrived successfully, without any types of failure.

Comment: so these http codes will force the Onfailure to be fired ; 401, 403, 404 ? is this correct ?

Comment: I do not know exactly, but I think so.